# How to resize a draw.io text box automatically to fit the text?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am new to draw.io, and find it tedious that after inserting a text box and typing text in it, I have to manually resize the text box such that the entire text fits in. Is there a shortcut to automatically resize the text box, such that it fits the text exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can autosize from the Arrange menu. It supports the operation on multiple cells:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a possibility that you fix the width and that the height of the text box is adjusted automatically?

Comment: @physicalattraction, If you turn on _word wrap_ in the _Format panel_, you can drag the handles of a text box, and it'll keep wrapping the text to accomodate the new size. If you then only drag in the lower middle handle, it'll keep the width, or the right/left middle handle and it'll keep the height.

Comment: This control is now a little square box with arrows pushing out the top and right sides. It only says Autosize if you hover over it. At least in my chart.

Comment: @physicalattraction. Someone created an issue requesting this functionality, here: 
https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/2732.